# what is /*** CONSTANTS ***/ and /*** STORAGE ***/ in solidity?

Tags: solidity, cryptokitties

I was going through cryptokitties contract and I found following two words

```
/*** CONSTANTS ***/



/*** STORAGE ***/
```

Are these any keywords in solidity or do they have any significance?

Comment: Why was this downvoted twice? It's a fair question if you're totally new in this.

Comment: The reason i asked this question was both of them appeared in blue color in remix online compiler. And usually reserved words are highlighted in blue in remix.

Comment: It's only a fair question if the community thinks it is, I'm afraid :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are just comments. There just for people reading the code to know what that section of code is about.

Solidity does have keywords `constant` and `storage`.